# ¿Cómo copiar una lista desplegable de Excel con Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Os cuento, tengo un fichero excel (**Libro.xls**), en una casilla tengo una lista desplegable con opciones, y lo que necesito es copiar esa casilla a otra del mismo fichero, es decir, la casilla D3 copiarla a F3. Esta operación si la hago con **control+c en D3** y **control+v en F3**, funciona perfectamente, y tengo la lista desplegable en F3, pero claro, quiero hacer esta acción con Java, me apoyo en la Api de Apache POI.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo la operación de copiar y pegar con Apache POI, pero solo se copia el valor que tiene la casilla y no se copia la lista desplegable.

Los métodos que uso son:

```
package es.fips;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class Excel {
    private static HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private static FileInputStream fis = null;
    private static HSSFSheet sheet = null;

    public static boolean enlazaExcel(String pathExcel) {
        // Cargar la ruta del fichero Excel.
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(pathExcel);           
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        // Linkeamos el documento excel.
        try {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            cargaHoja(0);
            return true;            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean cargaHoja(int numHoja){  
        try {
            // Obtenemos la hoja.
            int hojas = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            if((hojas-1) < numHoja){
                throw new Exception("El fichero excel solo contiene "+hojas+" hojas.");
            }else{
                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(numHoja);
                return true;    
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public static boolean guardaCambios(String dirTemp, String name){     
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        // Crear fichero de salida para el nuevo excel.         
        try {           
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dirTemp+"/"+name);           
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }                           
        // Los cambios realizado en la plantilla los guardamos en el nuevo excel.
        try {
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            return true;            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void cierraExcel(){
        try {
            if (workbook != null) {
                workbook.close();
            }
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }               
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void copiaCelda() {
        // Obtener la fila de las casillas origen, destino.
        Row newRow = sheet.getRow(2);// Fila 3.
        Row sourceRow = sheet.getRow(2);// Fila 3.

        // Obtenemos el valor de origen, creamos casilla destino.
        Cell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(3);// Columna D.
        Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(5);// Columna F.

        // Copiamos ESTILO de origen y se lo damos a destino.
        HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

        // Si la celda tiene comentarios, lo copiamos.
        if (newCell.getCellComment() != null) {
            newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
        }
        // Si la celda tiene links, los copiamos.
        if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
            newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
        }

        // Le damos el mismo TIPO de dato de origen a destino.
        newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

        // Le damos el valor de origen a destino.
        switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Para ejecutarlo, en su clase Main, usamos las siguientes llamadas.

```
package es.fips;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Excel.enlazaExcel("LaUbicacion/Libro.xls");
        Excel.copiaCelda();
        Excel.guardaCambios("LaUbicacion", "New.xls");
        Excel.cierraExcel();
    }
}
```

El fichero excel resultante es **Nuevo.xls** y su contenido es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como copiar la lista se lo agradecría mucho.

Comment: Respecto a lo que te decia en la pregunta que borraste, que haras cuando encuentres respuesta aqui o en SOeng? borraras la otra?

Comment: No, el idioma es distinto y el dominio también, por tanto, son dos contextos distintos. En tal caso, la auto contesto si nadie lo hace.

Comment: encontré esto sobre nuestro problema *etico*  (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76/si-tengo-algo-nuevo-qu%C3%A9-preguntar-debo-preguntarlo-en-ambos-sitios)

Comment: Genial! Pues lo que pienso está correcto ^^